# API development/Error - OPTION & POST request a the same time that cause 429 error

Tags: python, api, openai-api

the issue seems to be related to the API rate limit being exceeded when both the OPTIONS and POST requests are made at the same time. This can happen because the OPTIONS request, which is a preflight request for cross-origin requests, is also subject to the rate limit.

the error:

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
--
[03/Jun/2023 03:06:41] "OPTIONS /process_prompt HTTP/1.1" 200
[03/Jun/2023 03:06:50] "POST /process_prompt HTTP/1.1" 429
```

this is my source code :

```py
import os
import time
from threading import Thread, Lock
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, jsonify
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import (
    create_vectorstore_agent,
    VectorStoreToolkit,
    VectorStoreInfo
)
import tenacity
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, create_access_token, jwt_required, get_jwt_identity
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
jwt = JWTManager(app)

# Configure the database connection
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = '********'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = '***********'

# Create a User model for the database
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

# Create the database tables
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

lock = Lock()  # Lock for thread safety

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

# Raise an exception if the OpenAI API key is not set
openai_api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

# Initialize Streamlit-related components outside the Flask app
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.1, verbose=True, openai_api_key=openai_api_key)

# Create and load PDF Loader
directory_path = './docs'  # Replace with the actual directory path
file_names = [file for file in os.listdir(directory_path) if file.endswith('.pdf')]

def load_pages_from_files():
    pages = []
    for file_name in file_names:
        file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, file_name)
        loader = PyPDFLoader(file_path)
        pages.extend(loader.load_and_split())
    return pages

def create_chroma_db(pages):
    return Chroma.from_documents(pages, collection_name='rapport')

def create_vectorstore_info(store):
    return VectorStoreInfo(name="rapport", description="rapport", vectorstore=store)

def create_toolkit_and_agent(vectorstore_info):
    toolkit = VectorStoreToolkit(vectorstore_info=vectorstore_info)
    return toolkit, create_vectorstore_agent(llm=llm, toolkit=toolkit, verbose=True)

# Initial setup
pages = load_pages_from_files()
store = create_chroma_db(pages)
vectorstore_info = create_vectorstore_info(store)
toolkit, agent_executor = create_toolkit_and_agent(vectorstore_info)

# Define a function to handle the API request with retries
@tenacity.retry(wait=tenacity.wait_random_exponential(multiplier=1, max=10), stop=tenacity.stop_after_attempt(5))
def process_prompt_with_retry(prompt):
    response = agent_executor.run(prompt, language='fr')  # Set the language parameter to 'fr' for French
    return response

# Route handler for the OPTIONS request
@app.route('/process_prompt', methods=['OPTIONS'])
@cross_origin()
def process_prompt_options():
    response = make_response()
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST')
    return response

# Route handler for the POST request
@app.route('/process_prompt', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def process_prompt():
    prompt = request.json.get('prompt')
    if not prompt:
        return make_response(jsonify({"error": "No prompt provided"}), 400)
    
    try:
        with lock:
            response = process_prompt_with_retry(prompt)
        return jsonify(response)
    except tenacity.RetryError:
        return make_response(jsonify({"error": "API rate limit exceeded"}), 429)

@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    username = request.json.get('username')
    email = request.json.get('email')
    password = request.json.get('password')

    if not username or not email or not password:
        return make_response(jsonify({"error": "Please provide username, email, and password"}), 400)

    hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('utf-8')
    new_user = User(username=username, email=email, password=hashed_password)
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify({"message": "User registered successfully"}), 201

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    email = request.json.get('email')
    password = request.json.get('password')

    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

    if not user or not bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
        return make_response(jsonify({"error": "Invalid email or password"}), 401)

    access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.id)
    return jsonify({"access_token": access_token}), 200

@app.route('/protected', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required()
def protected():
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return jsonify({"user_id": current_user}), 200

@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def get_users():
    users = User.query.all()
    user_list = []
    for user in users:
        user_data = {
            'id': user.id,
            'username': user.username,
            'email': user.email
        }
        user_list.append(user_data)
    return jsonify(user_list)

@app.route('/users/<user_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_user(user_id):
    user = User.query.get(user_id)
    if not user:
        return make_response(jsonify({"error": "User not found"}), 404)
    
    db.session.delete(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({"message": "User deleted successfully"}), 200

def update_chroma_db():
    global store, vectorstore_info, toolkit, agent_executor
    while True:
        pages = load_pages_from_files()
        store = create_chroma_db(pages)
        vectorstore_info.vectorstore = store
        toolkit, agent_executor = create_toolkit_and_agent(vectorstore_info)
        time.sleep(300)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start the update function in a new thread
    update_thread = Thread(target=update_chroma_db)
    update_thread.start()

    # Start the Flask app
    app.run()
```

I tried to prevent the OPTIONS request from being made for the /process_prompt endpoint, i modified the CORS configuration to exclude the OPTIONS method for that specific endpoint. I achieve this by using a custom CORS configuration with the CORS extension in Flask. but seems doesnt works

```py
# Import the Flask and CORS modules
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

# Create the Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# Define CORS configuration
cors_config = {
    "origins": "*",  # Allow requests from any origin
    "methods": ["GET", "POST"],  # Allow GET and POST requests
    "allow_headers": ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],  # Allow specific headers
    "expose_headers": ["Content-Type"],  # Expose specific headers
    "supports_credentials": True,  # Allow credentials (cookies, Authorization header, etc.)
    "max_age": 3600,  # Set max age for preflight requests
}

# Apply the custom CORS configuration to the app
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/process_prompt": cors_config})

# Route handler for the /process_prompt endpoint
@app.route('/process_prompt', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(methods=["POST"])  # Enable CORS only for POST requests on this endpoint
def process_prompt():
    prompt = request.json.get('prompt')
    if not prompt:
        return make_response(jsonify({"error": "No prompt provided"}), 400)
    
    # Rest of your code

# Rest of your code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```